# How can I get a certain data in a JSON file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get only the insights in each data in a JSON format. I use lodash in filtering it by month but I cannot get only the insight in each object.

```js
let insight5 = [{
    insight: "valid",
    reportMonth: "January - June 2018"
  },
  {
    insight: "invalid",
    reportMonth: "January 2018"
  },
  {
    insight: "valid",
    reportMonth: "February 2018"
  },
  {
    insight: "valid",
    reportMonth: "March 2018"
  },
  {
    insight: "valid",
    reportMonth: "April 2018"
  },
  {
    insight: "valid",
    reportMonth: "May 2018"
  },
  {
    insight: "valid",
    reportMonth: "June 2018"
  },
];


function filterData(data, month) {
  let filtered = _.filter(data, x => x.reportMonth == month)
  return filtered[0];
}
```

Comment: What are you passing into `filterData()` when you call it and what are expected results? Not really clear what you mean by *"insights"* or what specific problem is

Comment: You don't want `filter`, you want `find` in order to get *one* result from the array (assuming the `reportMonth`s are unique), no library needed. Then just access its `insight` property (if an object is found in the first place)

Comment: the data is the insight5 and the month is from my interface, I want to get the insight from each corresponding month

Comment: I want to use filter first to get the right month, then I want to get ithe insight of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the insight, you need to return that property:

```
return filtered.length > 0 && filtered[0].insight;
```

I check the length first in case no matching data is found.

Comment: I want to filter it by its corresponding month

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain JavaScript [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Code:

```js
const insight5 = [{insight: "valid",reportMonth: "January - June 2018"},{insight: "invalid",reportMonth: "January 2018"},{insight: "valid",reportMonth: "February 2018"},{insight: "valid",reportMonth: "March 2018"},{insight: "valid",reportMonth: "April 2018"},{insight: "valid",reportMonth: "May 2018"},{insight: "valid",reportMonth: "June 2018"}];

const getInsightForMonth = month => insight5
  .filter(o => o.reportMonth.includes(month))
  .map(o => o.insight);
  
console.log(getInsightForMonth('February'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var desiredMonth = "February";
let insight5 = [{
    insight: "valid",
    reportMonth: "January - June 2018"
  },
  {
    insight: "invalid",
    reportMonth: "January 2018"
  },
  {
    insight: "valid",
    reportMonth: "February 2018"
  },
  {
    insight: "valid",
    reportMonth: "March 2018"
  },
  {
    insight: "valid",
    reportMonth: "April 2018"
  },
  {
    insight: "valid",
    reportMonth: "May 2018"
  },
  {
    insight: "valid",
    reportMonth: "June 2018"
  },
];


const filteredData = insight5.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
  if (currentValue.reportMonth.includes(desiredMonth)) {
    acc.push(currentValue.insight);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try lodash `get` directly. Returns `null` by default if `filtered` is empty.

```
return _.get(filtered[0], 'insight', null);
```